# Visual Studio - Windows-universal-samples UWP - How to trace into

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I have downloaded the Windows-universal-samples located in Github.  I have run one of the samples as a C# project.  I would like to trace into one of the calls (DeviceInformation.Pairing.PairAsync() in the DeviceEnumeration sample).  If I press F12, I get the metadata, not the source.

If I set a breakpoint and try to trace into:

1. With the project set as it came, it skips over it.
2. Setting the solution Properties|Debug|Debugger Type from "Managed Only" to "Mixed (Managed and Native), then I can trace into the function, but it doesn't find the source.  It says deviceinfo.cpp not found.  If I select Browse, it brings up a file dialog saying the original location is onecoreuap\base\devices\rtenum\dllsrv\deviceinfo.cpp, and wanting me to pick a location on my computer.

The proper boxes are checked in Tools|Options|Debugging|Symbols to use Microsoft Symbol Servers and in the Modules Window most of the modules say Symbols loaded.

I have tried deleting the .suo file as suggested in another post.  This doesn't help.

What do I have to do to get the source instead of the metadata and to be able to find the source (presumably deviceinfo.cpp) when stepping into.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to make Microsoft release Windows source code.

Comment: This is part of the UWP runtime, I don't think MS releases the source (someone might correct me as some of .NET is available)

Comment: I agree with @Richard Critten...

Comment: The framework of UWP app  is not open source. If you met any issues you could detail the issue to let people help you more.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. My problem is really that Bluetooth on this computer discovers but fails to pair (all BT devices), returning "Encryption Failed" from the call described. Hardware seems to be ok (sees the devices and reports their properties correctly).  Have no idea why.  Doesn't seem like a programming question, what I use Stack Overflow for.